# Sorting algorithm, possibly a new one

Tags: c++, beginner, sorting, reinventing-the-wheel, iterator

I'm a beginner who has never seen a sorting algorithm's implementation and have decided to try make one on my own (can someone tell me if this has been already used?).

The fact is I have never used iterators, but since I wanted to make this more generic I decided to quickly look them up.

Also, can anyone suggest what to do if someone passes the same iterator twice?

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename container>
inline void
sort
(typename container::iterator beginning,
 typename container::iterator end       )
{
    typedef typename container::value_type type_contained;
    typename container::iterator beginning_original_state = beginning;
    while (beginning <= end)
    {
        if (*beginning > *(beginning + 1))
        {
            // Gotta change the name to something more meaningful
            auto check_back(beginning);

            while (check_back != beginning_original_state && *check_back < *(check_back - 1))
            {
                std::swap(check_back, --check_back);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ++beginning;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (Have a look what [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) does.)

Comment: @greybeard I tried looking at g++'s implementation after finishing this sort algorithm but it's too convoluted

Comment: With regard to `what to do if someone passes the same iterator twice`, you could notice that `std::sort()` specifies a half-open interval [first, last) *excluding* `last`, including `first` *if* different from `last`.

Comment: H*** s*** that ADL lookup was really evil. Is the result the same on release build?

Comment: @Incomputable yes unfortunately ahaha it's all good

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Algorithm

What you have implemented is called [(linear) insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). It is very old, sorry your method is not new or novel ;) It has average case O(n^2) time complexity which is basically unusable for anything with more than a few thousand/tens of thousands elements. I recommend that you study the classic algorithms: [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), [(Cocktail) Shaker Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort), [Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), [Shell Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort), [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), [Heap Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), [Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) and [Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

There is a classic video from 1981 that is part of many CS curriculums called [Sorting out Sorting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJwEwA5gOkM) which is very illustrative and a recommended watch.

## Code

You never use `type_contained` remove it.

Once the unused type is removed you can change your template parameter to the iterator type directly and get rid of a lot of typing. This also allows template parameter deduction so that you don't have to explicitly state the container type as a template parameter.

Please don't reuse the argument `beginning` as a variable. It is hard to read when your iteration variable is named begin with another being original begin. Simply make a copy of begin, call it `it` for iterator or `current`.

Typically when two iterators are used to represent a range we use the names: `first` and `last`. To not confuse with `begin()` and `end()` and avoid a name collision when some one uses `using namespace std;`  (which you shouldn't!).

In general I'm not fond of your naming. For example `check_back` could simply be `previous`.

You don't need the inline specifier. You need a better algorithm. The compiler will automatically inline if it makes sense.

## Bug

In the code here:

```
while (beginning <= end)
{
    if (*beginning > *(beginning + 1))
```

you will dereference the `end` iterator + 1 which is beyond the end of the range. Also note that typically one expects the first iterator to be inclusive and the second to be exclusive (as is returned from `begin()` and `end()` on containers). So when used as expected your code will go 2 elements outside of the range. This results in undefined behaviour.

Also here:

```
std::swap(check_back, --check_back);
```

you are swapping the iterators, not the values they point to. Which means that the code doesn't even work at all. It gets stuck in an infinite loop, always. Not only that, but the order in which the arguments are evaluated is undefined so this type of code might not work if the `check_back` variable is decremented first.

You would have noticed all of the above if you tried to use this code in any way before posting to review. For future reference, we only review *working* code and this question is actually off-topic due to it not working at all.

## Cleaning it all up and fixing the bugs we get:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Iterator>
void sort(Iterator first, Iterator last){
    auto it = first+1;
    while (it < last){
        auto prev = it;
        while (prev != first && *(prev-1) > *prev){
            std::iter_swap(prev-1, prev);
            prev--;
        }
        it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it, it actually does work exactly as posted.

Comment: Never heard of [Cocktail Shaker Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort) very cool.

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni [It does not work as posted](https://ideone.com/JJ6lFY).

Comment: @EmilyL. What the hell, apparently I was calling a sort function which is in the global namespace. But I don't get it, I didn't import std::sort, how is this possible?

Comment: @EmilyL. Sorry. I really don't know why I got a function named sort in the global namespace, the worst part is I didn't specify the template parameters, so it didn't give me any compiler errors. I'm really sorry.

Comment: @EmilyL. Apparently it was because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753759/why-is-a-sort-function-in-the-global-namespace

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni As explain in this answer, your algorithm does not works as written as you are comparing items out of range. This answer clearly explains problems with your code and even show how to write much better code. You should read more C++ books and learn to use a debugger!

Comment: @Phil1970 I know but read my comments, I didn't go in-depth because everything seemed to work. Also I know how to use a debugger.

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni, it is actually combination of SFINAE and ADL. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748423/how-does-this-template-type-deduction-and-overload-resolution-work)